# Getting SyntaxError when trying to add version to javascript imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a SPA application where I use ES6 module imports. I do not use Webpack at all in this project. But when I tried adding a version to my .js files I got an error

```
import `./store.js?v=${cr_version}`
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string

Or using the + syntax

```
import `./store.js?v=` + cr_version
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+'

How could I add versioning to my .js files, is there some other syntax that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` must be a primitive string and can't be a template or a function call.

This way the code structure can be analyzed, modules can be gathered and bundled into one file by special tools.

But you can use the `import()` function, i.e.:

```
await import(`./store.js?v=${cr_version}`);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sad that it has to be a primitive string

Comment: I found [this article](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports), maybe it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Static imports can only use static strings.

If you want to dynamically determine the module name at runtime, you need to use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports).

```
import(`./store.js?v=${cr_version}`).then( store => {
    // do things with store
});
```